# appcompat-v7 abc_alert_dialog_material.xml Lint error

Tags: android, google-play-services

my project has `android:minSdkVersion="9"` and uses `appcompat-v7` lib.
When I run `Lint`, following error is shown:

> Multiple annotations found at this line:
>     - To support older versions than API 17 (project specifies 9) you must *also* specify    gravity or layout_gravity="start"
>     - Attribute "textAlignment" is only used in API level 17 and higher (current min is 9)

The corresponding code fragment is

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.DialogTitle
            android:id="@+id/alertTitle"
            style="?attr/android:windowTitleStyle"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAlignment="viewStart"/>
```

Adding `android:gravity="start"` doesn't help because `Gravity.START` requires API level 14.

Also there is a `Lint` error

> Call requires API level 11 (current min is 9)

for the following files in `v7_appcompat` lib:

```
android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle in notification_media_action.xml
android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle in notification_media_cancel_action.xml    
android:attr/dividerHorizontal in notification_template_big_media_narrow.xml
android:attr/dividerHorizontal in notification_template_big_media.xml
```

What can I do?

Comment: Why can't you add the Gravity? It just won't be used for API less than 14

Comment: I'm afraid it could cause app crash on devices with api < 14. Or will that attribute just be ignored?

Comment: You could try it... I think it'll be ignored just like the message that says *Attribute "textAlignment" is only used in API level 17 and higher*... It looks like a warning, not an error

Answer (score 1):

use gravity and set left instead of start .

```
android:gravity="left"
```

Comment: When I put this, the Lint message is "Multiple annotations found at this line:
 - Attribute "textAlignment" is only used in API level 17 and higher (current min is 9)
 - Inconsistent alignment specification between textAlignment and gravity attributes: was left, expected 
  start)

Comment: remove textAlignment attribute and only use gravity